{{< pagebreak >}} in Quarto html output
I have a simple Quarto file (book), and when I try to add a page break, it doesn't work with HTML output.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: HTML
---

# Hello

{{< pagebreak >}}

# Goodbye


Try format: html. Then the pagebreak works. Please note that pagebreak in HTML is only visible when you want to print it.

Thank you, Julian. What if I want a page break in the preview? Do I need to add a new quarto file and work with as many files as pages I want?
